# BorderLayout align

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, border-layout

I have a **JPanel** with a **BorderLayout**. In the **Center** of this **JPanel** I have another **JPanel** with **GridBagLayout**. I want to add vertically in the second **JPanel** some **JLabels** from top left corner. I need **BorderLayout** because I need to add my title in the **North** area.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the `GridBagLayout`, you can use easier `BoxLayout`:

```
public class Popup {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame window = new JFrame("Title");

      window.add(new JLabel("North", JLabel.CENTER), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      window.add(new JLabel("South", JLabel.CENTER), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      window.add(new JLabel("West"),  BorderLayout.WEST);
      window.add(new JLabel("East"),  BorderLayout.EAST);

      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
      centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

      centerPanel.add(new JLabel("Here"));
      centerPanel.add(new JLabel("Here"));
      centerPanel.add(new JLabel("Here"));
      centerPanel.add(new JLabel("Here"));

      window.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      window.setSize(600, 400);
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      window.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```